# Adding % wildcards to my SQL query causes a syntax error

Tags: sql

I have this script:

```
$sql4='SELECT prod_name,description,price,in_stock,plat_name,genre_name FROM product WHERE prod_name LIKE %:prodname%';
$query5=$db->prepare($sql4);
$query5->execute(array(':prodname'=> $_GET['product']));
$result2=$query5->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And it's giving me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%'some text'%'

I know that those percent signs are the problem. If I remove them the code works just fine, but how do I get it working *with* those signs? I need them because I want to select all records containing given string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to write your code like this:

```
$sql4='SELECT prod_name,description,price,in_stock,plat_name,genre_name FROM product WHERE prod_name LIKE :prodname';
$query5=$db->prepare($sql4);
$query5->execute(array(':prodname'=> '%'.$_GET['product'].'%'));
$result2=$query5->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Where now, PHP will correctly format the query as `".. like '%yourValue%'"`.

Do you see the difference?

```
SELECT prod_name,description,price,in_stock,plat_name,genre_name FROM product WHERE prod_name LIKE '%'some text'%' -- (Wrong)

SELECT prod_name,description,price,in_stock,plat_name,genre_name FROM product WHERE prod_name LIKE '%some text%' -- (Correct!)
```

Comment: I think the incorrectly prepared query is actually `… LIKE %'some text'%`. The outer quotes in `'%'some text'%'` are part of the error message.

Comment: Excellent that you showed the final SQL for the right and wrong. In solving problems of this nature, it is important to show what the SQL it is trying to execute resolves to, then the error is almost always obvious.